# Condensing code in a 2d Array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, integer, sum

I want to condense the following code. I am looking for a way to initialize a,b,c, and d in one line to zero, and also for a way to condense the try/catch blocks.

Another question: if I do not explicitly state a, b, c and d to be zero, why are they not 0 by default? I think its because they are not initialized, if this is the reason how can I initialize the integers without using 4 lines for them?

I am aware that there are probably other shorter methods to solve this problem and I would like to see them, but I would also like to see a shorter trycatch method to this problem.

```
    //returns sum of tiles adjacent to (x,y) in the 2d array specified

    public static int sumAround(int[][] array, int x,int y){
    int a,b,c,d;
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    d = 0;
    try{
        a = array[x][y+1];
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    }

    try{
        b = array[x][y-1];
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    }

    try{
        c = array[x+1][y];
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    }

    try{
        d = array[x-1][y];
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    }

    return a + b + c + d;




    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create another method to be called from this method

```
private int getVal (int[][] array, int x,int y) {

     try{
        return array[x][y];
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println ("AIOOB");
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

then you can simply call as

```
int a = getVal (array, x, y+1);
int b = getVal (array, x, y-1);
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about the try...catch statements and what their function is.  But to condense the ints (a,b,c,d), you can try something to just define all of them in the same line. As of which:

int a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0;

This will work given that definitions can be separated by a comma on the same line.  This can also work with just simply defining variables without declaration (variables don't always need declaration).

Answer (score 0):

```
a = b = c = d = 0;
```

Also, in general it's a bad idea to catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, as it is to capture other RuntimeExceptions such as NullPointerException.  Instead, check the size of the array before doing x + 1 or y + 1.  For the x - 1 or y - 1, I'm assuming that you're only at risk if you go negative, if the x, y are larger than the initial array then that would seem to be bad data that should cause an InvalidArgumentException of some sort to be thrown.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
public static int sumAround(int[][] array, int x, int y) {
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
        try {
            a = array[x][y + 1];
            b = array[x][y - 1];
            c = array[x + 1][y];
            d = array[x - 1][y];
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

        }
        return a + b + c + d;
    }
```

Comment: if `b` line throws an Exception then `c` and `d` will be be called

Comment: do something in your catch block

Comment: if the first throws exception so you will directly go to catch block

Comment: you can also add some checks before to do x-1 or y-1

Answer (score -1):

1. The integers you have defined are local variables. In java, local variables will not be initialized by default, but the variables in class will initialized as 0 by default(if you do not assign them with other values). So, you have to initialize this four values.
2. Why not try to throw an exception. In your case, it is meaningless to catch an exception, since it will still return a "correct" result which is actually nothing!

try this:

```
public static int sumAround(int[][] array, int x,int y) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
    return array[x][y+1] + array[x][y-1] + array[x+1][y] + array[x-1][y];
}
```

Comment: I want the edge cases to work, so array[0][0] will return array[1][0] + array[0][1]